# Stripping the class from a methodtype obtained via decltype

Tags: c++, types

I want to strip a class from a method type so that I have a function type left to work with.

`stripClass` has faked behavior that shows how I what I want as a result from the call `stripClass(decltype(&A::B))`.

The other lines show my general understanding.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#define stripClass(type) void() //fake implementation of what I want to happen

struct A
{
    void B() {}
};

int main()
{
    decltype(&A::B) declTypeB = &A::B; //decltype of method
    void (A::* decl)() = &A::B; //explicit type of method

    void(*f)(); //function pointer thype when class type would be stripped from it
    std::function<void()> fromFunction = f;

    std::function<stripClass(decltype(&A::B))> fromDecltype = f;
    return int{ 0 };
}
```

How can I strip the class from a method to get a function pointer while preserving the return type and the parameters.

Comment: `A::B` is [not valid syntax](https://ideone.com/fChu4y). Beware of Microsoft-isms.

Comment: @n.m. That sounds terrifying.

Comment: It also isn't very clear why you need this. How are X and stripClass(X) related?

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the feedback - updated the snippet

Comment: @n.m. this is something for a homebrew c++ stub framework that I am playing around with. ultimately I want to one line making a mock and have injectable members

Comment: @n.m. do you recommend any static checkers that I could use in vs to make sure I do get a warning when I use a Microsoft-ism?

Comment: Use a different compiler to check :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a type trait, can be also specialized to process argument / result types or deal with qualified methods differently:

```
template<typename x_PointerToMethod> class
t_SignatureExtractor;

template<typename x_Class, typename x_Returned, typename... x_Args> class
t_SignatureExtractor<x_Returned ( x_Class::* )(x_Args...)> final
{
    public: using
    t_ExtractedSignature = x_Returned (x_Args...);
};

template<auto x_p_method> using
t_ExtractedSignature = typename t_SignatureExtractor<decltype(x_p_method)>::t_ExtractedSignature;

...

t_ExtractedSignature<&A::B> * f{};
```

Comment: I am getting `template<auto x_p_method> using`  auto not supported here on my machine.

Comment: It looks like I am not on C++17

Comment: @Johannes template alias just makes things convenient, you can still use this code by supplying `decltype(&A::B)`

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the trait for any member pointer, as it'd work just the same whether they're functions or objects:

```
template <class MemberPointer>
struct as_free_pointer;

template <class C, class T>
struct as_free_pointer<T C::*> {
    using type = T *;
};

template <class MemberPointer>
using as_free_pointer_t = typename as_free_pointer<MemberPointer>::type;
```

Comment: `as_free_pointer_t` is a function type, not a function pointer type? Also your template parameters are messed up.

Comment: @PasserBy gah. Why do I keep editing code right in the answer box like it's somehow a good idea...

Comment: @Quentin I can not get this to compile. Am I using this incorrectly? `#define stripClass(type) as_free_pointer_t<type>`

Comment: @Johannes I borked my first attempt, make sure you're using the current one. What's the error?

Comment: @Quentin It is a compiler error on the argument type of function. I think the problem is that it does not really work off the `decltype` result. but even when I use `&A::B` or `A::B` I still get a compile error.  I also do not full understand what this generates. If I had to guess I would say it extracts the class and what I need is everything but the class.

Comment: @Quentin also I menat to post this link for you: https://ideone.com/Ls6HOl

Comment: @Johannes okay, there are a couple problems in here: first, you need to pass `decltype(&A::B)` to get the type of the pointer, not the pointer itself. Then, `std::function` needs a function type instead of a function pointer type, so my trait doesn't work on its own... Anyway, VTT's answer does all of that already, I'll get my revenge later ;)

Comment: @Quentin  ;)  I thought it would be something like that. It is pretty clear to me now that I need to take a long and hard look at templates again.